# Shell-Script Python call fails with Syntax Error

Tags: bash, python-2.7, shell, ubuntu, virtualenv

I am currently preparing a shell script which as part of it's functionality has to carry out some Python calls.

```sh
PY_OP=$(python -c 'import my_package as mp; print mp.some_operation()')
```

However when I call my shell script in the bash I only receive a very strange syntax error:

```sh
$ ./my_script.sh
File "<string>", line 1
import my_package as mp; print mp.some_operation()
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Interestingly this error does not occur if I just execute the `python -c ...` command just from within the bash.

As additional information I can say the following:

- I am using a `virtualenv` to contain all `pip` installed packages.
- my Python version of use is 2.7.12
- my operating system is elementaryOS 0.4.1 (which however fully bases on Ubuntu 16.04)

Any suggestions or hints on what I am doing wrong would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I get these three lines: `Traceback (most recent call last):`, `File "<string>", line 1, in <module>` and `ImportError: No module named my_package`.

Comment: Check your file for special characters: `cat -A file.sh` or `cat -v file.sh`.

Comment: @Cyrus Thanks for the hint. `cat -A file.sh` already did the trick. When I ran it the `import` statement actually looked like this `importM-BM- my_packageM-BM- asM-BM- mp`. Even though those chars are invisible in a normal editor it was apparently what caused the script to fail.

In case you would simply copy the comment into an answer I would happily accept it as the correct solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments @Cyrus gave in response to the initial question I was able to solve the problem using the `cat -A {file-name}.sh` command.

Executing it on the file revealed the following:

- Expectation: `import my_package as mp`
- Reality: `importM-BM- my_packageM-BM- asM-BM- mp`

The unfortunate thing is that these `M-BM-` are not visible in normal editors like Atom or Sublime, but appear to have an influence when the `sh`-file is exected. This also explains the weird placement of the error point which is pointing to a white space (which in fact appears to be some special, non-visible character).